# Standalone Flash player app for swf -files

Tags: software-recommendation, adobe-flash

I use nowadays Opera because it just works for these swf -files. 
No other browser work.

However, the problem with Opera is that it is big.

**Is there any tool by which you can just view SWF -files?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you already visit Adobe?

Adobe provides a standalone Flash Player: [Flash Player Projector 16.0](http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/16/flashplayer_16_sa.dmg).
Additional also debugger versions are [available](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) as well as older versions.

Originally it was meant for Flex and Flash developers.

Example: Starting a flash game

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! I visited Adobe but could not find this application. I tried Flash Player which is addon in browsers.

Answer (score 1):

at
https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html
Download the "Flash Player projector"
at
https://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/32/flashplayer_32_sa.dmg
The second link will be updated. So use the first link.